# Analysis of algorithm about log log n

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Consider f(n) = log log (n) , g(n) = 10^10^10^10^10^10 , then f(n) is O(g(n)) .

Is that above consideration true or false ? Please Mention the reasons behind that consideration.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about algorithm complexity. It belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You seem to be applying Big-O notation to two mathematical equations.  What complexity do you wish to measure with it?  The normal ones are numbers of swaps or number of comparisons, number of passes, number of page faults, none of which apply to mathematical equations.

Comment: No wait, you're only applying Big-O to G, and asking if f==O(g)?  How weird...

Comment: *g(n)* seems to be constant, so you seem to be asking, if *log log n* can be computed in constant time?

Answer (score 1):

f(n) grows (albet very slowly), and g(n) is a constant.

lim n-> inf, f(n) / g(n) = 0, so this is false